# ¿Carpetas/archivos dentro del proyecto raíz sin ruta absoluta?

Tags: java, netbeans

Necesito ver los archivos y carpetas dentro del proyecto raíz.
Se que puedo colocar parámetro a el `new File("carpeta1")` y más abajo el `listFiles()` me devolverá los archivos que están dentro, pero, lo que quiero es acceder a todos los archivos del proyecto raíz, como por ejemplo que me devuelva el nombre de "carpeta1", anteriormente mencionada.

En otros lenguajes se usan palabras reservadas como "root" o "home" quizá, el funcionamiento de algo así es lo que busco.

**NO** quiero colocar una dirección absoluta.

```
public void archivos(){
    File carpeta = new File("carpeta");
        if (carpeta.exists()) {
            File[] ficheros = carpeta.listFiles(); //Listar archivos en carpeta
            for (File f: ficheros) {
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es aplicar `listFiles()`, pero a la carpeta raíz del proyecto?

Comment: Correcto, como explique arriba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otras opciones:

- Usar `.` como ruta relativa

  ```
  File carpeta = new File(".");
  ```
- Usar el `parent` de la direccion absoluta de una relativa:

  ```
  File carpeta = new File("carpeta").getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();
  ```

Ambas formas deberian obtener la carpeta de ejecucion actual.

Comment: Vi el método mientras buscaba y no se me ocurrió.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar obteniendo el directorio de trabajo de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String directorioRaiz = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println("Directorio de trabajo = " + directorioRaiz);

    archivos(directorioRaiz);
}

public static void archivos(String directorioRaiz) {
    File carpeta = new File(directorioRaiz);
    if (carpeta.exists()) {
        File[] ficheros = carpeta.listFiles(); //Listar archivos en carpeta raiz
        for (File f : ficheros) {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

Esto imprimirá **una ruta absoluta completa desde donde se inicializó tu aplicación**